# Show querystring after POST

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using MVC4/Razor. After a GET request the view shows the querystring, and after a POST request the view does not show the querystring - both as expected.

But, I have an action with `[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)]`, and I need to POST a form to it, and to show the corresponding querystring.

How can I do this on the server side? *I know this can be done on the client side by converting to a GET request, and I am curious to see how to do that, but only if that is the only way to make this work.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `return RedirectToAction` with posted parameters

```
return RedirectToAction("About", "Create", 
                      new { id = PId, Name=PName }); // more params if needed
```

The parameters will be included in the querystring.

Comment: OK, it works as you've written it, but I pass a `RouteValueDictionary` instead of individual params, and I drop the "__RequestVerificationToken" key. It redirects to the same action, which makes it look like a GET, and so sends a response with a querystring!

Comment: No security issues because it goes thru post first, but the route looks a little different. If you have id or param your route, it often doesn't honor the route but puts the params into the query string. The affect of parameter passing is no different tho. The Action Method gets every parameter the same way.

Comment: What I meant is removing the `__RequestVerificationToken` key makes me a little uneasy, but I think (?) the request needs to pass forms auth before it even hits my code.